# Sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I am new to Linux and everything. Please bear with me. I downloaded kernel 5.15 on ubuntu 20.04 gnome but was a mistake. I had 5.4 installed before and want to go back to it because my ssh isn't working neither is my xrdp and it was before. Can anyone help me out please? I am a noob and don't want to reinstall the image again for the 4th time lol. Thanks
This is the error I am getting:
[image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Copy and paste the output you get in your question.

Comment: what are your DNS resolvers? do you have any set up?

Comment: I couldn’t copy and paste, i tried. I do not have DNS resolvers. The hosting server has said to uninstall xrdp and reinstall it. Do you think that will help?